# KeyEventTranslations.tr at user directory

Tags: front-end, keyboard

I added some shortcut defintions to the system file `KeyEventTranslations.tr` and they work perfectly. However when I move the same definitions to a seperate file in my home directory (on Linux) `$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X`
those shortcuts are still working  but the cursor keys and some of other standard shortcuts (e.g. Ctrl+c,Ctrl+v for copy/paste) stop  working.

Comment: I noticed that these directories and files do not exist by default on my fresh installation on Windows 10 of version 12.2 of Mathematica. If you create the directories and files, Mathematica detects them and can apply your customizations.